# What flower is this blue flower?

Tags: botany

What flower is this? [image: some blue flower] All help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you add further information as to e.g. where you found it?

Comment: Was it spray-painted blue? Do you have a picture of the whole plant? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an image which shows the whole flower (ideally with some leafs)?

Comment: Species identification questions are on topic as long as sufficient details are provided. This question does not have enough details.

Answer (score 4):

Without more detail about the whole plant (including leaves), where it came from, and about whether or not it was spray-painted, watered with dyed water, etc. it would be difficult to ID.

It seems to be in the Asteraceae family, and in the pompon class, as seen in these vender's pictures. (Disclosure: I have no affiliation with the company.)

http://www.fiftyflowers.com/product/Blue-Cushion-Bulk-Flower_10.htm
http://www.fiftyflowers.com/product/Blue-Cremon-Bulk-Flowers_24307.htm
http://www.fiftyflowers.com/product/Electric-Blue-Flowers_10.htm

It is most similar to a blue chrysanthemum.

[image]
http://john-hallett.co.uk/2013/04/04/blue-crysanthemum/

[image]

Sources:

- as listed above for images
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysanthemum (pink image)
- http://www.mums.org/chrysanthemum-classes/